# I am trying to device an algorithm which can tell what a number is made of

Tags: algorithm

I am adding corresponding bits of two bit steams in Java like below:

```
1 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0
====================
2 0 2 1 1 0
```

After this I am adding result as:

```
2+0+2+1+1+0 = 6
```

**Now, I have to find out number of 1ns and 2s in the result (6) that is matched bits and non-matched bits**. I tried hard to device such an algorithm which can tell me exact number of 1ns and 2s the result is made up of but I am unable to create any so far.
It allows multiplying of each addition result with a constant number. Individual bits can be subtracted to achieve above goal.

Further detail:
I am using Pascal Paillier Homomorphic algorithm to encrypt these individual bits. Pascal Paillier supports addition only over encrypted data so I have to add only. I have to send this number to some application which have to find out the exact number of 1ns and 2s result is being made up of.

**Update:**
I can also multiply these individual bits like I am adding above. But I cannot add these bits neither the result. Bits can be multiplied with itself or any other bit. Even I can represent these bits with number of my choice. That is I can say that 1=2 and 0=3 then I can have:

For addition (Pascal Paillier):

```
2 3 2 2 3 3
2 3 2 3 2 3
====================
4 6 4 5 5 9
```

For Multiplication (RSA)

```
2 3 2 2 3 3
2 3 2 3 2 3
====================
4 9 4 6 6 9
```

**The only purpose is to find out the number of similar bits (1&1) and non similar bits (0&1, 1&0) from the overall  number will be generated** either by addition (Pascal Paillier) or by multiplication (RSA).
Furthermore, 2nd bit-stream can be represented with different numbers than the above.

Following can also be used:

1. Multiplication with bits and results and exponential with a constant
2. Addition/Subtraction among bits and result and multiplication with a constant only

Comment: Are you trying to solve equation x+2y=z with a given z?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but any time a 2 would be used it can be replaced by 2 1's.  This means whatever algorithm you would use for this would map a number to 1 or more answers.

Comment: Can you just count the number of 1's and 2's as you calculate them? There is no way to go backwards from 6, since 0, 1, and 2 are all options, and two 1's makes one 2.

Comment: I think this is my case. I think i cannot solve this.

Comment: @Dan you are right. It is almost not possible I think to find out this. But may be someone can come up with an out of the box idea to get me out this.
I cannot count these. These are going to be encrypted by Pascal Paillier encryption.

Comment: This question is unsolvable by any logical methods. All you can do is hit and trial.

Comment: @displayName by using multiplication over exponential we may come up with something which can tell which bits are similar (1&1) and which are different (1&0 or 0&1). With addition and multiplication we can find this but no algorithm supports these both properties.

Comment: Somebody voted my question down even without a reason. People like these should not have such powers ..

Comment: Now that you have accepted your own answer (`send` an encoding of the sequence of comparison results), _what has been the question_? `The only purpose is to find out the number of similar bits (1&1) and non similar …` doesn't tell whether this asks how to derive this from the total pop(ulation) count (`6` in your 1st example) (which is impossible generally), or how to transfer this information (let n be the number of bits: going from ld(4)n to ld(3)n sucks, when encoding those numbers using 2ld(n) bits would do. (Use _to devise_ (conceive) instead of (machine), give `bit steams` that r.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution of my question. Here is the algorithm to find out 1ns and 2s:

Steps:

Add encrypted streams
After addition message space will be of [0,1,2]
A polynomial of base 3 will be created on resulting output like a1X^1, a2X^2 .. anX^n where a1..an are the output of cipher text addition and belongs to [0,1,2] and X=3
All polynomial terms will be added
By using log of base 3 we will find power of 3 which is closed to 'no'
An Array bits[] will be used to keep track of 1ns and 2s

```html
 no =  sum_of_polynomial_terms
log_base = 3
while (no > 0)
{
    x1 = Find_log(no, log_base);
    no = no - log_base^x1;
    bits[x1]++;
}
```

Comment: So, with two sequences of six bits each and a sum of `6` as in your question, how many positions show a `1` in both, and how does the receiving application learn this? What is `a` - the sequence of sums? Can you elaborate on item 6 - how does it relate to `send this number to some application which have to find out the exact number of 1ns and 2s result is being made up of`?

Comment: Yes **a** is sum of corresponding bits of two steams. I am calling it bits as they are zeros and ones otherwise it is being treated as integers. bits[] will be of size 6 and initialized with zeros. X1 will tell the index in bits[] and will be incremented each time **no** will be less than (**no - power (3, closest power near to no)**).

Comment: Also, any application which knows the log_base can find out the matched 1ns.

Answer (score 0):

As @sbelaikov pointed out in his comment, the math just doesn't allow for this.

You have an end result of the sum of an array of numbers which could be 0, 1, or 2. In your example this number is 6. We'll call this `sum`.

`sum` is equal to the number of ones plus the number of twos times two.

`sum` = `ones` + (2 * `twos`)

You have one known variable, which is `sum`. You have two unknown variables, `ones`, and `twos`. To solve the system of equations, you need another equation. You have insufficient data.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as:
Let bit stream length is 7:
then Max sum = 14 and Min Sum = 7. Now 1s = Max sum - sum while 2s = sum - min sum. But this holds only for size of 7 bit stream.

Comment: For a 7 bit stream, it is determined if the sum is 14, 13, 0, or 1. Otherwise, there are multiple combinations of 0s 1s and 2s that would create that sum.

Comment: I have updated description and now with the provided information can you please think of something now ? I am still unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question correctly: if you want to find out how much 1ns and 2s a number x is made of, there is no unique solution. 
Imagine the number `100`. Now tell me how many ones and twos are in there. 100 ones and 0 twos? 0 ones and 50 twos? Or maybe 80 ones and 10 twos?

Another example: Your are given a number `x` and `y` whereas `x` is a divisor and `y` is a remainder from a division.

Let's set `x` to 3 and `y` to 2. Now find the dividend. Again, it is not possible because 11 / 3 leaves 2, but also : 14 / 3; 17 / 3; 20 / 3 and so on..

There are two possibilities what you can do:

- Somehow grab the numbers before they get sum'ed up
- Or, if useful in your case, calculate all combinations of 1ns and 2s which sum up to your target number. **But:** If you try to do this you will probably face the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is **NP-Complete**.