# Algorithm to find out matched bits and non matched bits from two streams

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I am adding corresponding bits of two bit steams in Java like below:

```
1 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0
====================
2 0 2 1 1 0
```

After this I am adding result as:

```
2+0+2+1+1+0 = 6
```

**Now, I have to find out number of 1ns and 2s in the result (6) that is matched bits and non-matched bits**. I tried hard to device such an algorithm which can tell me exact number of 1ns and 2s the result is made up of but I am unable to create any so far.
It allows multiplying of each addition result with a constant number. Individual bits can be subtracted to achieve above goal.

I can also multiply these individual bits like I am adding above. But I cannot add these bits neither the result. Bits can be multiplied with itself or any other bit. Even I can represent these bits with number of my choice. That is I can say that 1=2 and 0=3 then I can have:

For addition (Pascal Paillier):

```
2 3 2 2 3 3
2 3 2 3 2 3
====================
4 6 4 5 5 9
```

For Multiplication (RSA)

```
2 3 2 2 3 3
2 3 2 3 2 3
====================
4 9 4 6 6 9
```

**The only purpose is to find out the number of similar bits (1&1) and non similar bits (0&1, 1&0) from the overall  number will be generated** either by addition (Pascal Paillier) or by multiplication (RSA).
Furthermore, 2nd bit-stream can be represented with different numbers than the above.

Following can also be used:

1. Multiplication with bits and results and exponential with a constant
2. Addition/Subtraction among bits and result and multiplication with a constant only

Further detail:
I am using Pascal Paillier Homomorphic algorithm to encrypt these individual bits. Pascal Paillier supports addition only over encrypted data so I have to add only. I have to send this number to some application which have to find out the exact number of matched bits and non-matched bits.
Also, I can use RSA but it only allow multiplication.

Comment: Please clarify how this question is different from your already answered [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769305/i-am-trying-to-device-an-algorithm-which-can-tell-what-a-number-is-made-of). (There are few algorithms to encrypt _individual bits_.) Are you allowed to use _both ciphertexts_?

Comment: @greybeard  Sir in the previous one I asked only for addition. Now here i asked to check similar bits by any means given the provided rules. Though it is not different and I have flag that question for deletion already.
I can use a single algorithm at a time.

Comment: Isn't that what's added in edit six in the question linked? If you can clearly state what's different, please do so in the question proper - don't comment comments. If you want this question to include "multiplication"/"RSA" and the question linked not to, consider rolling back that question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, from two original streams of bits *a* and *b*, you will want to perform something like

```
popcnt(a XOR b) = # of non-matching bits (pairs of 0,1 and 1,0)
popcnt(a AND b) = # of matching 1-bits (pairs of 1,1)
```

where *popcnt* is the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of the resultant string.

If you happen to be compiling it on a processor which supports the SSE4 POPCNT instruction (AMD and Intel processors produced in the last 7 years), this will likely be the most performant way of solving the problem. As an example, an implementation for both (testing an int-sized number of bits from streams *a* and *b* at a time)

```
int nonmatch(int a, int b) {
    return __builtin_popcount(a ^ b);
}

int match(int a, int b) {
    return __builtin_popcount(a & b);
}
```

will yield assembly code

```
; nonmatch
xor    %esi, %edi
popcnt %edi, %eax
retq

; match
and    %esi, %edi
popcnt %edi, %eax
retq
```

respectively.

Comment: how can i perform AND and XOR operations on encrypted text ? the bits showing as zeros and ones would be like as: 141337303076331496843088211497813030703